# Invert image faster in C#

Tags: c#, .net, colors, picturebox

I'm using WinForms. I have a picture-box in my form. When I open a picture in the picture-box I am able to invert the colors back and forth on a click of a button, but my code is extremely slow. How can I increase the performance.

```
   private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
     {
        Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image);
        for (int y = 0; (y 
                    <= (pic.Height - 1)); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; (x 
                        <= (pic.Width - 1)); x++) {
                Color inv = pic.GetPixel(x, y);
                inv = Color.FromArgb(255, (255 - inv.R), (255 - inv.G), (255 - inv.B));
                pic.SetPixel(x, y, inv);
                PictureBox1.Image = pic;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are setting the control's picture each time you change a pixel, which causes the control to redraw itself.  Wait until you've finished the image:

```
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image);
for (int y = 0; (y <= (pic.Height - 1)); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; (x <= (pic.Width - 1)); x++) {
        Color inv = pic.GetPixel(x, y);
        inv = Color.FromArgb(inv.A, (255 - inv.R), (255 - inv.G), (255 - inv.B));
        pic.SetPixel(x, y, inv);
    }
}
PictureBox1.Image = pic;
```

Comment: @D Stanley Thank you for explaining and giving an example. It worked like a charm.

Comment: `Get`/`SetPixel` is awfully slow. Google for `LockBits` and use that - you can get results orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I'll look into that. I'm not so familiar on how to use LockBits in this case though. If you can give an example I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @taji01 there are countless questions on this topic on this site, just search around and you'll find more than what you'd expect ;)

Comment: I found a couple but i don't know how to incorporate it into a button click like how i have it. @LucasTrzesniewski

Comment: This is a terrible example! - Don't use!!

Answer (score 0):

Improving on D Stanley's suggestion and avoiding the memory and processing overload of converting the image to a Bitmap and then re-assigning it, you can actually directly Get and Set pixels on the .Image of the PictureBox by simply casing it and calling the associated Bitmap manipulation functions:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
 {
    for (int y = 0; (y 
                <= (PictureBox1.Image.Height - 1)); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; (x 
                    <= (PictureBox1.Image.Width - 1)); x++) {
            Color inv = ((Bitmap)PictureBox1.Image).GetPixel(x, y);
            inv = Color.FromArgb(255, (255 - inv.R), (255 - inv.G), (255 - inv.B));
            ((Bitmap)PictureBox1.Image).SetPixel(x, y, inv);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case someone need the similar code in VB.NET.

Also note the variable inv.A instead of the value 255. In case your picturebox has transparency you need this.

```
    Public Function InvertImageColors(ByVal p As Image) As Image
        Dim pic As New Bitmap(p)
        For y As Integer = 0 To pic.Height - 1
            For x As Integer = 0 To pic.Width - 1
                Dim inv As Color = pic.GetPixel(x, y)
                inv = Color.FromArgb(inv.A, 255 - inv.R, 255 - inv.G, 255 - inv.B)
                pic.SetPixel(x, y, inv)
            Next x
        Next y
        Return pic
    End Function
```

Usage:

```
    pic.image = InvertImageColors(pic.image)
```

Comment: People! Just because you personally dislike vb.net, there are LEGACY applications out there that must be MAINTAINED. This is a USEFUL answer. Thanks Isidoros.