# How to invert an image

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a png image to be set on a button:

```
Button btn = new Button();
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\temp\dog.png", UriKind.Relative));
btn.Background = brush;
```

I would like to have it inverted (meaning negative image).

Something like:

```
btn.Background = Invert(brush);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invert image faster in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024881/invert-image-faster-in-c-sharp)

Comment: As a note, UriKind.Relative with an absolute URI looks dubious.

Comment: @AliBahrainezhad that is for winform, I am using wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code below. Note that it currently only works for PixelFormats with 32 bits per pixel, i.e. `Brg32`, `Bgra32`, `Prgba32`.

```
public static BitmapSource Invert(BitmapSource source)
{
    // Calculate stride of source
    int stride = (source.PixelWidth * source.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

    // Create data array to hold source pixel data
    int length = stride * source.PixelHeight;
    byte[] data = new byte[length];

    // Copy source image pixels to the data array
    source.CopyPixels(data, stride, 0);

    // Change this loop for other formats
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 4)
    {
        data[i] = (byte)(255 - data[i]); //R
        data[i + 1] = (byte)(255 - data[i + 1]); //G
        data[i + 2] = (byte)(255 - data[i + 2]); //B
        //data[i + 3] = (byte)(255 - data[i + 3]); //A
    }

    // Create a new BitmapSource from the inverted pixel buffer
    return BitmapSource.Create(
        source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight,
        source.DpiX, source.DpiY, source.Format,
        null, data, stride);
}
```

You can now use it like this:

```
brush.ImageSource = Invert(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\temp\dog.png")));
```

---

So
[image]
becomes
[image]